# How to make query using google app engine endpoint for android?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an Android project using google app engine endpoints. We tried to insert a new query in an automatically generated endpoint class (I have a Poll.java class and a PollEndpoint.java class) in the server side, but the system doesn't work because a red cross is showed on the AppEngine part of the project. No other error message are shown.

Code insert in PollEndpoint.java class:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getLastPoll")
public Long getLastPoll(@Named("date") Date date, @Named("creator") String creator) {
EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
Key id = null;

try {
        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select keyPoll from Poll where creator
     =" + creator + " and creationDate = " + date);
        id = (Key)query.getSingleResult();
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return id.getId();
}
```

Is it correct to do query in this way?

Comment: When you say a red cross is being shown, is it because there is a compilation problem in the project ? Please specify.

Comment: Yes, I found the compilation problem and I solved it: the return type can't be of type Long.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a red cross on the project but can't see any errors I suggest you look at the errors/warning view (I think that's what its called).  You haven't specified your IDE so I'm assuming Eclipse.

Most often it is a problem with your build path.